# Software using Socket Based TCP connection cannot connect to server

Tags: windows, tcp

On my computer other network based software are able to connect to servers and I am able to surf the internet as well on this computer however there is a software that uses socket based tcp connection however upon starting that application it reports "No connection". How can I resolve this. How to resolve/troubleshoot socket based tcp connections issues.

Comment: This question is much to vague to be answered.  A lot more detail is needed to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the TCP port number that the application uses?  If so, make sure that a firewall isn't blocking that port number.  For example, many ISPs block TCP port 25 to the internet (the only exception is their own internal SMTP server so that all their customers can send eMail) to prevent direct-to-MX spamware from sending junk eMail.

P.S.:  Most internet-based applications use TCP sockets.  One great example is the web browser, which uses mostly TCP ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS).